# Connecting to DB Context with C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a API setup doing all of calls to the database, but there is one occasion in a website that cannot make a call api call for some reason. And only thing I can think of is just doing a quick call to the database in the website itself. I just want to run a quick linq query against my database. What is the proper hard coded connectionstring settings, and how can I plug in my GlobalDAtacontext as well. Thanks for any help.

```
//Example of what I would like to do
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("WHAT IS THE PROPER CONNECTIONSTRING FORMAT")
{
    conn.open();
    using (var context = new dbcontext())
    {
          var user = (from x in context.users where x.ID == userid).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string depends on your database configuration. What kind of configuration you are using to connect to database, whether you are using windows auth or user/pass auth. Default database comes into play.

Various [Sql Server Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) connection are given here. You can choose one that suits your need.

You need to pass the `SqlConnection` object to the `DbContext` constructor while initializing it.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;")
{
    conn.open();
    using (var context = new dbcontext(conn, true /* it can be false too, */))
    {
        var user = (from x in context.users where x.ID == userid).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I cannot with a IP adress?